# @NotNull in spring boot not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, nullable

This is my DTO class:

```
public class AppDTO implements Serializable {

    private String appId;

    private Date dateCreated;

    @AppFeaturesValidation
    private Set<AppFeature> appFeatures;

}
```

The @AppFeaturesValidation validate the content of appFeatures.

This is the AppFeature class:

```
public class AppFeature {

    private String packageId;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean isEnabled;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean isDisplayed;

}
```

When I send to this value null - it gets it.
In the same project, a different type using @NotNull is working.
The same imports for this annotation, just a simpler object:

```
public class packDTO implements Serializable {

    private String packId;

    private Date dateCreated;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean clone;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add @Valid for the appFeatures Set, so the validations will be checked for each of the elements.